# Drawing points to image defined in QML from C++ in QT

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have an *image* item defined in **QML** and I need to paint points to this *image*, which I have in my **C++** **QVector**. I wanted to use **QPainter**, but I don`t know where to paint, because I dont know how to get a **Pixmap** or **QWidget** from  such object. Any idea how to paint points (from **C++**) on the image defined in **QML**?

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    objectName: "window"
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Item {
        id: item1
        anchors.fill: parent
            Image {
                id: myPicture
                objectName: "myPicture"
                x: 0
                y: 0
                width: 640
                height: 370

                anchors.fill: parent
                source: "picture.jpg"
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you need? If you want it will look like you paint on the image just add `Rectangle`s as children of `item1` at appropriate coordinates. If you want to modify the image itself just implement your own item from `QQuickPaintedItem` with custom logic.

Comment: I have one image as a map, a and I need to paint on it points (X,Y) which coordinates I`m receiving from server. When I was not using QML I did it using ```QImage tmp(ui->label->pixmap()->toImage());``` and then ```QPainter painter(&tmp);``` and so on .. but now, its something like that not possible.

Comment: `QQuickPaintedItem` allows you to paint whatever you need. Just reimplement [QQuickPaintedItem::paint()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickpainteditem.html#paint)

Comment: Thank you @folibis